# scala : creating temp directory and file

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to create a temp directory and file underneath it. Here is my code snippet:

```
var tempPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")
val myDir = new File(tempPath.concat(scala.util.Random.nextString(10).toString))
myDir.mkdir()

val tempFile = new File(myDir.toString+"/temp.log")
```

This code is working fine. However I am wondering if there is any better way of doing this, please provide your comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java has existing methods that can do this for you, like [`Files.createTempFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-), [`Files.createTempDirectory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempDirectory-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) and their overloads.

You can find some examples [in this blog post](https://softwarecave.org/2014/02/05/create-temporary-files-and-directories-using-java-nio2/).